# Ignition Key Replacement

Tags: ignition, ignition-key

I live in Calgary I shipped a 1998E=Class320 to Nigeria and i lost the key. Am going to Nigeria in June how can I get a replacement without the car here in Canada.

Comment: Goto the dealer with your vin number, your drivers license and the title.  they will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Goto the dealership**

If you goto the dealership for the manufacturer of your car you can bring some things with you to get a key, possibly.

- Drivers license, passport
- VIN Number of your vehicle
- Title of the car - with your name on it.

The dealership can cut you key.  IF your key needs to be programmed into your cars system you will need to get an authorized dealership to associate your key with the car.  You'll need your ID and the title again.

Good luck.